# Why Git won't easily enable programs to output their version (commit hash)

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

If I understand correctly there is no built-in functionality in Git to simply let the program output which version or which commit hash string it is when it is run. Why not? Would it not be a simple feature of git (or any other similar system) to generate a plain-text file in the repository with the latest commit hash string in a list, for the program to read when it runs so that I can query the running program for which version it is.

Currently I have added this functionality manually myself to several rather different projects in many different languages and it feels like I am repeating myself and that this feature should be part of git (or github/gitlab) itself.

What I would like is to solve the problem once and for all so that whenever I use git then it would be a simple task to make a running program tell which version it is.

I suppose that the easiest way to achieve it would be to let git generate a text file with the latest commit hashes and release versions for the repository. Would that do? Or is this problem already solved in some way that I am not aware of?

**Solved (once and for all(?))**

I think what I was looking for is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893631/108207). I could make it work as described by adding the `.gitattributes` file and then the `$Id$` will work just like it did in CVS.

So what I did was adding the `.gitattribute` and then I can do this in my program:

```
fn print_version() {
    let version = format!(
        "Version: {}",
        "$Id: 3c044d47e723cd4e079e402dab29128b3631dbc6 $"
            .replace("$Id: ", "")
            .replace(" $", "")
    );
    print!("{}", &version);
}
```

The above id will be replaced at checkout and the function will print the version id (the commit id).

Comment: See [Git keyword substitution like those in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534655/git-keyword-substitution-like-those-in-subversion), this should basically provide what you are looking for.

Comment: Why do you assume this is a common problem? I don't claim long experience in SW development. But I never ever used that kind of information. Also, why do you believe running programs right from git repository is common?

Comment: @Euphoric Yes, it's a useful thing to have.  It means that a "Help->About" dialog can tell you the exact version of the software.  Even the venerable SCCS from 1972 could to it.

Comment: Again. Why do you believe the program will run from git repository? Last time I checked, 99.99% of all software runs outside it's repository. That means that the information has to be put there during compilation. And compiler can put that there by simply calling git status.

Comment: Git is a general purpose version control system, so while it's widely used in software development, this feature wouldn't be core to its function.

Comment: Is there anything you are missing from `git describe`? It is guaranteed to be unique and monotonically increasing, provided you have a sane tagging strategy.

Comment: To me, a commit hash and the version of the software are two different things. You might tag commit `abc12345` as version 2.0, but I don't know that anybody besides developers cares about the commit hash over seeing version 2.0 in Help->About.

Comment: `Would it not be a simple feature of git...` I think the obvious answer is that Git already provides enough extension points for you to accomplish this yourself. Git has been successful by focusing on its core competencies.

Comment: @Euphoric: the OP most probably gave a slightly wrong description - I guess he means "generate a plain-text file in the **working directory**, from the repo", not "in the repository". That is what causing the confusion here. So this is not about "running programs in the repo".

Comment: @DocBrown I think what I was looking for is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893631/108207). I could make it work as described by adding the `.gitattributes` file and then the `$Id$` will work just like is did in CVS.

Comment: @Euphoric Because when doing a release of a new version, it can be important to quickly see exactly what has changed i.e. what is the diff between this release and the previous, and even more fundamental to actually verify that the new release actually is running and that it is not still the old release/version. Seeing the diff between two commits is easy but only if you have the two commit ids. So we need a way to get the commit ids from running project that have been released so that we can match the running app with actual versions of the source code. I updated my answer with a method now.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz: did you notice, you can write an answer to your own question *as an answer* (and accept it), not just as part of your question. And yes, I understood perfectly what you meant, though your wording is pretty confusing (you don't want git to *"generate a plain-text file in the repository with the latest commit hash string in a list"*, you want a keyword substitution feature which can replace a placeholder in a source file by the latest commit hash string).

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz Your solution does *NOT* put the commit id in the file. It puts the file's own blob hash into the file, i.e. it hashes the file's contents, and puts that resulting hash in. Technically, this is very similar to how CVS works, in that it is specific to the file (although, if two files have the same contents, they'll have the same blob hash, even if one was just created and the other has had hundreds of revisions), but it is *not*, as you say, the commit id. If you change and commit a different file, it will change the commit id, but have no effect on the hash in this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is not the job of the SCM to maintain version numbers of executables.
In my experience with Java, it is Maven or Gradle that does the build, tags files in SCM and produces the executable artifact for a particular software version. The built executable is typically deployed to a container like Nexus.
However this does not mean it is easy to access the  version number in the build tool but that is a different question.